# Issue with Ajax.ActionLink incorrectly rendering links when using htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, rendering, actionlink

Does anyone know of any issues with rendering incorrect querystrings when using htmlAttributes in an Ajax.ActionLink?  It seems that if I put even an empty array in for the htmlAttributes, the link gets rendered incorrectly.  Here's my code.

When I do this (note the new { }):

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Milestone", new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", Model.Id } }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ModalDeleteContainer", OnSuccess = "modalDelete" }, new { })%>
```

The link renders like this:

```
<a href="/Client/1/Admin/Milestone/Delete?Count=1&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: 'GET', updateTargetId: 'ModalDeleteContainer', onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, modalDelete) });">Delete</a>
```

When I do this (null instead of new { }):

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Milestone", new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", Model.Id } }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ModalDeleteContainer", OnSuccess = "modalDelete" }, null)%>
```

The link renders like this:

```
<a href="/Client/1/Admin/Milestone/Delete/703c749e-c145-4cf1-90eb-9bee00bac79d" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: 'GET', updateTargetId: 'ModalDeleteContainer', onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, modalDelete) });">Delete</a>
```

The only difference between the two is the htmlAttributes argument at the end of the Ajax.ActionLink.  Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct overload of the method. The one you are using takes an IDictionary and that's why it's rendering the way it is.

If you choose the object RouteValues and object htmlAttributes like this:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Milestone", new { id = Model.Id }, 
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ModalDeleteContainer", 
OnSuccess = "modalDelete" }, new { })%>
```

it will all work!