# Ajax.ActionLink AjaxOptions not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using this overload:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Match", "Match", "User", new { userId = Model.userId, matchId = match.id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "test" }, new { })
```

('match' is an instance variable within a foreach)

but neither POST nor my "test" confirm are working. I found another SO question stating it may be due to a JavaScript error on page elsewhere, but I have none according to FireBug.

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761288/issue-with-ajax-actionlink-incorrectly-rendering-links-when-using-htmlattributes) question which seems to be telling me I'm doing it correctly. I thought I was using the wrong overload, but can't find a better match. What's wrong?

Edit: The links are also being rendered /User/?userId=blah&matchId=blah, if that's relevant

Comment: Make sure the controller action matches the params what you are passing [new { userId = Model.userId, matchId = match.id }].

Comment: It does - if I remove [HttpPost], it will call the method and pass the parameters appropriately. But I need it to be POST, and the POST parameter is just not being recognized, nor any other options I place in AjaxOptions {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have added jquery unobtrusive ajax scripts on the page if you are using jquery otherwise you have to include microsoft ajax scripts on the page

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js and my links are now behaving properly.